# How can I show extra data using a textbox when clicking a table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting web development with ASP .NET MVC4 and I'm stuck with the following problem:

I need to display certain fields of a viewmodel in a table, and when a row is selected or clicked display extra data in another div with textboxes. This is because the wiewmodel has to many fields and I want to display the more important data in the table (no need to scroll in the screen) and the less significant data bellow the table in another div (similar to outlook mail client functionality, when you select an email the body of the email is displayed below).

So I think to resolve this I need to know the selected row argument item.A and then with AJAX retrieve the extra data related to item.A.

Some generic code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.B)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C)
    </td>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Z)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I tried several Jquery and javascripts scripts to achieve this with no success, so I think I'm missing something.

Here an example script

```
<script>
    $('tr').click(function () {
        alert('values: ' + $(this).data('A'));
    });
</script>
```

Note: Just using alert to test the script, later I will replace it with the AJAX call.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: not sure what you tried to do in jQuery here... can you inspect some elements in your browser ant attach the fully rendered tags?

Comment: Store the ID of the item in the rows `data` attribute - `<tr data-id="@item.ID">`, then in the script, access it and use [$.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to call a controller and update the contents of the `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr data-id="@item.A">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.A)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.B)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C)
        </td>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Z)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('tr').click(function () {
            alert('values: ' + $(this).data('id'));  //you will get item.A value
//do ajax call here and add partial view html data to div 
        });
    });

</script>
```